# File permissions of backup files

Tags: backup, permissions

Emacs (26.1) is putting highly restrictive permissions on backup files.  This is causing a problem where multiple people are editing the same files.  Here's an example: I created a file called test.txt with the permissions:

-rw-rw-r--. 1 wtthomps ssc 16 Mar 19 14:30 test.txt

I then edited this file, which gave me the following permissions:

-rw-rw-r--. 1 wtthomps ssc 22 Mar 19 14:31 test.txt
-rw-------. 1 wtthomps ssc 16 Mar 19 14:30 test.txt~

I then changed the permissions on test.txt~ to 664 and did another edit.  This time the permissions were as expected:

-rw-rw-r--. 1 wtthomps ssc 26 Mar 19 14:37 test.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wtthomps ssc 22 Mar 19 14:31 test.txt~

I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: What's the default permissions for newly created files (as eg defined by umask on unices) ?